# Change HTTPS Wordpress using Docker NGINX

Tags: wordpress, docker, ssl, nginx, https

I have a Wordpress website using Docker and works fine. I'm trying configure HTTPS and not works. I changed the `siteurl` and `home` into the `wp_options` table.

I'm trying use this tutorial, but it's not working (results We were unable to establish a secure connection with this site 80.241.208.103 has sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR):

https://websitesetup.org/http-to-https-wordpress/

Look this configuration:

**NGINX:**

```
server {
    server_name    brau.io www.brau.io;
    root           /var/www/brau.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://80.241.208.103:8083/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/brau.io-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/brau.io-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = brau.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name    brau.io www.brau.io;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**wp_config.php**

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: explain 'not works' a bit more. Listening on interfaces? What error messages?

Comment: @danblack, I updated the question. You can try access the link https://brau.io

Comment: Ok. So https://brau.io is redirecting to https://brau.io//. First .htaccess isn't read by nginx so has no effect. Avoid `if` conditions in nginx, put two server definitions for different names. What is being used to run the php page (http://80.241.208.103:8083/ is another nginx instance)? Whatever it is, does it pass the headers though to PHP the same way to make those `$_SERVER` values valid.

Comment: 8083 are a container docker port. I'm using wordpress into docker container